# Repetitive bot event notifications in slack

Tags: events, slack, slack-api

I have subscribed to channel notifications for my bot in Slack.I am receiving repetitive event notifications from slack with same timestamps. Generally, if one request fails then slack tries the same request again after some time  but the requests I am receiving are all with same timestamp.
Any idea, how to stop these instantaneous repetitive notifications?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your question. Please post the relevant part of your code, so people can help you solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Thank you for your response. I have subscribed to following bot events in slack.
1.member_joined_channel
2.message.channels
3.message.im
As I have subscribed to event message.channels , I should get event notification from slack when a message is posted in a channel. The problem is , I am receiving this notification for same message  twice almost instantaneously(same timestamp) due to which bot also gives response twice which is not desired.
I want to know if there is way to stop theses repetitives notifications from slack.

Comment: Hey, again. Please post your code. They can be many reasons why this happens. Not much value in speculating.